# pandas index filter non datetimes

Tags: python, date, pandas

I'm reading in a csv file with a date time column that has randomly interspersed blocks of non date time text (5 lines in a block at a time and sometimes multiple blocks in a row). See below for an example snipped of the data file:

Date,Time,Count,Fault,Battery
12/22/2015,05:24.0,39615.0,0.0,6.42
12/22/2015,05:25.0,39616.0,0.0,6.42
12/22/2015,05:26.0,39617.0,0.0,6.42
12/22/2015,05:27.0,39618.0,0.0,6.42
,,,,
Sonde STSO3275,,,,
RMR,,,,
Default Site,,,,
X2CMBasicOpticsBurst,,,,
,,,,
Sonde STSO3275,,,,
RMR,,,,
Default Site,,,,
X2CMBasicOpticsBurst,,,,
12/22/2015,19:57.0,39619.0,0.0,6.42
12/22/2015,19:58.0,39620.0,0.0,6.42
12/22/2015,19:59.0,39621.0,0.0,6.42
12/22/2015,20:00.0,39622.0,0.0,6.42
12/22/2015,20:01.0,39623.0,0.0,6.42
12/22/2015,20:02.0,39624.0,0.0,6.42

I can read the data from the clipboard and into a dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

I am looking for a way to clean the 'Date' column of non date formatted strings prior to converting to a datetime index. I have tried converting the column to an index and then to a list and filtering like this:

```
df.index=df['Date']
df = df[~df.index.get_loc('RMR')]
df = df[~df.index.get_loc('Default Site')]
df = df[~df.index.get_loc('X2CMBasicOpticsBurst')]
df = df[~df.index.get_loc('Sonde STSO3275')] 
df = df.dropna()
```

I can then parse the dates and times together and get a proper datetime index using date parse tools.
However, the contents of the text fields can change and this approach seems very limited and non-pythonic.

Therefore, I'm looking for a better, more flexible and dynamic method to automatically skip these non date fields in the index, hopefully without having to know the details of their contents (e.g. skipping a 4 row block when a blank line is encountered).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use to_datetime

```
df.loc[:, 'Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, errors='coerce')
```

element that is not a datetime would be transformed to NaT
then you can drop it.

```
df = df.dropna()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""Date,Time,Count,Fault,Battery
12/22/2015,05:24.0,39615.0,0.0,6.42
12/22/2015,05:25.0,39616.0,0.0,6.42
12/22/2015,05:26.0,39617.0,0.0,6.42
12/22/2015,05:27.0,39618.0,0.0,6.42
,,,,
Sonde STSO3275,,,,
RMR,,,,
Default Site,,,,
X2CMBasicOpticsBurst,,,,
,,,,
Sonde STSO3275,,,,
RMR,,,,
Default Site,,,,
X2CMBasicOpticsBurst,,,,
12/22/2015,19:57.0,39619.0,0.0,6.42
12/22/2015,19:58.0,39620.0,0.0,6.42
12/22/2015,19:59.0,39621.0,0.0,6.42
12/22/2015,20:00.0,39622.0,0.0,6.42
12/22/2015,20:01.0,39623.0,0.0,6.42
12/22/2015,20:02.0,39624.0,0.0,6.42"""
```

```
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), parse_dates=[['Date','Time']])
df = df.dropna()
df['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date_Time, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M.%S")
print df
             Date_Time    Count  Fault  Battery
0  2015-12-22 05:24:00  39615.0    0.0     6.42
1  2015-12-22 05:25:00  39616.0    0.0     6.42
2  2015-12-22 05:26:00  39617.0    0.0     6.42
3  2015-12-22 05:27:00  39618.0    0.0     6.42
14 2015-12-22 19:57:00  39619.0    0.0     6.42
15 2015-12-22 19:58:00  39620.0    0.0     6.42
16 2015-12-22 19:59:00  39621.0    0.0     6.42
17 2015-12-22 20:00:00  39622.0    0.0     6.42
18 2015-12-22 20:01:00  39623.0    0.0     6.42
19 2015-12-22 20:02:00  39624.0    0.0     6.42
```